# How to scroll ul li element automatically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment, jquery-mobile

I have a problem. I'm making a jquery based chat, and I'm wondering how could I append/prepend a LI element from a *.js file.

index.html:

```
<html>
...
<div id="divID">
  <ul id="ulID"></ul>
</div>
</html>
```

chat.js:

```
$('#ulID').append(msg);
```

What I want to do is a classic chat container which will be populated, and automatically scrolled to the last LI element.

Comment: So you just need to append the `<ul>` with `<li>`s containing the new messages?

Comment: Replace `append(msg)` with `append('<li>' + msg + '</li>')` and you are done?

Comment: So you want it to automatically scroll down is what you're trying to say?

Comment: Well, I need my chat container to be scrolled always at the last item.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explained myseld right.

Comment: @veredesmarald: the msg var is already put in li tags

Comment: @ksemeks: So the append() call isn't working correctly? Or is the only problem you have making the box scroll automatically?

Comment: @veredesmarald: the append is working correctly. I want to know how to make the box scroll automatically. And if possible, with the scrollbar not visible.

Comment: @ksemeks: Then I would suggest you name your question something like "How do i get an element to scroll automatically" instead of "How to append li element at the bottom of a ul". :)

Answer (score 1):

with jQM you can use the Silent Scroll method

```
$.mobile.silentScroll (method)
```

Decos: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/methods.html

as for adding a li to a ul list, just remember to use:

```
listview('refresh')
```

for jQM to add it's CSS/JS functionality.

I would also suggest looking at the listview docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/../../docs/lists/index.html

Answer (score 0):

After the comment exchange above, it appears the actual question being asked is **"How can I make an element scroll automatically, and if possible, with the scrollbar not visible?"**

A similar question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462937/scroll-content-automatically-in-an-overflownone-element-jquery).